# Transition matrices with 2 bases

Tags: linear-algebra, transition-matrix

My question is about Transition matrices, I want to ask the following question:

Given a Linear transformation $T:R^2\to R^2,$ Such that:

$$T(x, y) = (3x-y, x-2y).$$

Let $B$ be basis for $R^2$ such that:

$$B=\bigl((1, 1), (2, 5) \bigr) $$

- Use **transition matrices** to calculate $[T]^B_B$ by $[T]^E_E$ .

I tried to calculate it by the following formula:

$$[T]^B_B=[I]^E_B[T]^E_E[I]^B_E$$

and i got wrong result, I know other ways to calculate it, but i have no choice and it must to be done by transition matrices and $[T]^E_E$ , any suggestions?

Comment: When you write $[I]_E^B$, is this the matrix of the identity map from $\mathbf{R}^2$ to $\mathbf{R}^2$ using the standard basis (I assume this is what $E$ is) on the domain and the basis $B$ on the codomain? Also, what does $C$ have to do with anything?

Comment: $E$ is the standard basis. you right, the basis $C$ is not part of the question, I will correct it by editing the question.

Comment: If you’d like someone to explain what you’re doing wrong, then show your work instead of expecting us to read your mind.

Comment: Dear @D.Rotnemer, You did not answer my main question. What is the meaning of the notation $[I]_E^B$? If it is what I expect, then the correct formula is $[T]_B^B=[I]_E^B[T]_E^E[I]_B^E$.